# Injecting Ctrl+C into target process

Tags: c++, windows

I have a process that has a CtrlBreak handler by calling `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`. This handler listens for `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` and performs some action (without quitting). This process is not attached to a console. Let's call this the target process.

Next, I have written a separate program which takes a PID and I'd like to start a remote thread at the address of `kernel*!CtrlRoutine` so that the CtrlBreak handler of the target process is executed, e.g.:

```
hRemoteThread=CreateRemoteThread(hRemoteProc, NULL, 0,
     (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)dwEntryPoint,
     (void *)CTRL_BREAK_EVENT, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);
    ResumeThread(hRemoteThread);
```

The problem is, how do I find the address of `kernel*!CtrlRoutine` in the remote process (`dwEntryPoint`)?

I saw an example where a program registered its own CtrlBreakHandler, then walked up the stack using __asm to get the address, but this code doesnt work correctly on Windows 2008 Server.

Just to note, I cannot recompile the target process, so I have to do this without modifying the target process.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft provides a [GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683155(v=vs.85).aspx) for this purpose.

Comment: There are all kinds of restrictions on this function and it can't send the signal to an arbitrary process.

Comment: I tried using P/Invoke to create a console application in a new process group, specifically to use GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent to trigger it to close, but it has no affect, regardless of whether I pass the constant for CTRL+C or CTRL+BREAK along with the process id of the new process (which identifies the process group id according to the documentation).  The console application does in fact respond to CTRL+C and CTRL+BREAK when run in a console window, but when run without a console window (either CREATE_NO_WINDOW or DETATCHED_PROCESS creation flags), GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DLL injection technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_injection) to achieve this. You do it by first creating a DLL whose DLLMain, registers the Ctrl-break Handler. Then you open the target process and write the path to your DLL in its address space using VirtualAllocEx and WriteProcessMemory. Then you launch a remote thread in the target process with LoadLibrary as the entry point and the address of the DLL path as the parameter.

This causes your DLL to be loaded in the target process and DLLMain to be called which will register the CtrlHandler.

You can do all the above things only if your application has privilages to write into target process.

You may refer to [this link](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet407.htm) for the sample code.

Comment: The link provided to sample code says "Forbidden: You do not have permission to access this document."

Answer (score 0):

You can send the WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP events to the window handle using the sendmessage api

Comment: But you really shouldn't do this. For starters, it rarely works. The app can check the current state of the control keys and determine that neither of them are down. Faking it with `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages isn't guaranteed to work. Second, you should really do this with `PostMessage`, rather than `SendMessage`, if you do it at all. And third, Windows already provides a perfectly good function to send keyboard input to other windows. It's appropriately named [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx); highly recommended.